# is it correct to use to in this expression: loss of morale to him

Tags: word-usage

Does the following sentence make sense? I mean the last part. 
Is it correct to use the `loss of something to someone` as an expression?

> The result of the medical test caused a loss of morale to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, morale isn't something that's transitive—you don't *give* it to (or *take* it from) somebody, even though you might cause them to gain or lose it. Morale is something that you have or don't have, it's not transferable.

Your sentence could be rephrased like this:

> The results of the medical test caused a loss of morale ***in*** him.

(Note that you normally get test *results*, plural.)

But although that's the right preposition, it's still a bit awkward.

---

More natural would be one of these phrases:

> The results of the medical test caused *him to lose morale*.
>   The results of the medical test *decreased his morale*.